# How to create combobox with images in Gtk?

Tags: c++, linux, combobox, gtk

Can anyone please tell me how to create a combobox like following with Gtk (on Linux)? (I already ask this question for win32 API).

[image]

A code example or tutorial will be very helpful. I have tried searching this over the internet, but unfortunately documentations/tutorials aren't that much rich for Gtk. Thank you very much.

Regards,

Answer (score 1):

I know how to do this in C, but I'll try to wing it in C++. First of all, use a `ComboBox` to display your menu, which you will fill using a `TreeModel`.

Create a `TreeModelColumnRecord` following the example [here](http://library.gnome.org/devel/gtkmm/unstable/classGtk_1_1TreeModelColumnRecord.html); you will need just one `Gdk::Pixbuf` column to display your line images.

Pass the `TreeModelColumnRecord` to the constructor of `ListStore`. Fill your `ListStore` with `Gdk::Pixbuf` images of your line patterns, and pass that to the constructor of your `ComboBox` (`ListStore` inherits from `TreeModel`).

Comment: Thank you very much. I'll try it, though I'm not sure I got all those :) Btw, in any chance  if you have an example please be kind enough to show it to me (C or C++). Thanks again.