# ComboBox with images GTK

Tags: image, combobox, gtk

how can i add images to ComboBox? I want to have text and at right image?

I have tried to implement it but well it did not work ^.^

Any advices needed

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to create combobox with images in Gtk?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3441561/how-to-create-combobox-with-images-in-gtk)

Comment: For Python and GObject introspection, see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15807611/247696)

Answer (score 8):

First you need a model to store items (text and images).

```
enum {COL_TEXT, COL_ICON, NUM_COLS};

GtkListStore *store = gtk_list_store_new( 2, G_TYPE_STRING, GDK_TYPE_PIXBUF );

/* add some data */
GtkTreeIter iter;
gtk_list_store_append(store, &iter);
gtk_list_store_set( store, &iter, COL_TEXT, some_text, COL_ICON, some_pixbuf, -1 );
```

Next you create `GtkComboBox` (or `GtkComboBoxEntry` and you can skip creating text cell renderer).

```
// GtkComboBoxEntry *combo = gtk_combo_box_entry_new_with_model( GTK_TREE_MODEL(store), COL_TEXT );
GtkComboBox *combo = gtk_combo_box_new_with_model( GTK_TREE_MODEL(store) );

GtkCellRenderer *renderer;

/* text cell */
renderer = gtk_cell_renderer_text_new();
gtk_cell_layout_pack_start( GTK_CELL_LAYOUT(combo), renderer, TRUE );
gtk_cell_layout_set_attributes( GTK_CELL_LAYOUT(combo), renderer, "text", COL_TEXT, NULL );

/* icon cell */
renderer = gtk_cell_renderer_pixbuf_new();
gtk_cell_layout_pack_start( GTK_CELL_LAYOUT(combo), renderer, FALSE );
gtk_cell_layout_set_attributes( GTK_CELL_LAYOUT(combo), renderer, "pixbuf", COL_ICON, NULL );
```